# Static initialization with private constructor

Tags: c++

In a class I have a static member that represents the singleton instance of that class:

```
class A {
public:
  static const std::shared_ptr<A> INSTANCE;
private:
  A();
};
```

In order to prevent more instances I made the constructor private. Now I have trouble to initialize the static var, because the initializer cannot access a private member. Here's the code I use in the .cpp file:

```
const std::shared_ptr<A> A::INSTANCE = std::make_shared<A>();
```

A factory method wouldn't help either, as it would have to be public as well. What else can I do to make this work? Note: I'd like to avoid the typical `static get()` method if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `make_shared`, but you can just create the instance directly:

```
const std::shared_ptr<A> A::INSTANCE { new A };
```

Comment: I'm baffled. Why can't make_shared() use that approach (or why has it trouble with the visibility while this variant has not)? Anyway, it works, so thanks :-)

Comment: `make_shared` is defined outside your class, so it can't access a private constructor.  But the initializer for a static member is considered part of the class definition, so it is able to access private members.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of a static member is unrelated to the constructor, so the global statement is indeed the right way to go. Is it not working for you?

EDIT: I just realized you're trying to avoid using a singleton access method for some reason. Sounds suspiciously like the [Borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/). :) Unrelated to you r specific question but I'd advise you to reconsider.